# (Google Sheet API) How do I add 10 to A1? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm new at API so this is probably a stupid question.

But how do I add 10 to A1 in a google sheet, in javascript?
I tried looking it up, but it never works, and I think I got something wrong.

Comment: What did you try till now? Do you have a code you're working on?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you have already authenticated your app to the API, if not, take a look at this quickstart guide for [Node.js](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) or [JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) browser side. This example is for the Node.js side.

I'm not entirely sure whether or not you're trying to add 10, or just update 10 to A1, the difference is whether or not we should take into account that there could already be another value in A1. Either way, you should use [update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update).

```js
const {
  google
} = require('googleapis');
const sheets = google.sheets('v4');

function main() {
  const spreadsheetId = 'your-spreadsheet-id' // TODO: Update placeholder value.
  const request = {
    majorDimensions: 'ROWS',
    values: [
      [10]
    ]
  }
  // TODO: Update placeholder value. Check out https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption for more info.
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.update(request, spreadsheetId, 'Sheet1!A1', {
    valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED'
  })
}
```

If the case is that you already have a value in A1, then you first need to use `sheets.spreadsheets.get` in a rather similar manner to get the value, count the sum of the addition, and then update the value in A1.

If you have any questions, please ask, and if I misunderstood your question, sorry about that.